# DualTransitionBuilder is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/widgets/dual_transition_builder.dart' and

Tags: flutter

After upgrading to version of Flutter 1.20.x I'm getting the following error when building for both iOS and Android.

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.0/lib/src/shared_axis_transition.dart:241:12: Error: 'DualTransitionBuilder' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/widgets/dual_transition_builder.dart' and 'package:animations/src/dual_transition_builder.dart'.
    return DualTransitionBuilder(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have done a Flutter clean several times, deleted and regenerated the iOS Podfile and manually deleted the flutter_build directory. Every time it regenerates the build with this error.

Answer (score 0):

It's known [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59659), fixed now. Increase the version to at least `1.1.1` in pubspec.yaml

```yaml
dependencies:
  ...
  animations: ^1.1.1
```

and run

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: Pavel, my app's pubspec.yaml did not include 'animations', I guess one of the plugins I use must use it.  I added animations: ^1.1.1 to my pubspec and it fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @KeithB, you can upvote an answer to indicate that it's helpful, and mark it as accepted to indicate that it solved the problem :)